# How to forward web traffic with iproute

Tags: networking, vpn

I'm trying to follow this guide from TinC on how to forward all webtraffic through a VPN tunnel to a safe internet connection.  Typical unsecure coffee shop connection type problem.

Anyway, I'm using TinC, and I can connect to the server no problem, but I'm not routing any internet traffic through this connection.  I'm sure of this because my public IP is still different from the IP I would expect back at the safe side of the VPN.

Here's the setup that connects, but has no interet traffic for tinc-up:

```
ip link set $INTERFACE up
ip addr add  10.0.0.3/32 dev $INTERFACE
ip route add 10.0.0.0/24 dev $INTERFACE
```

And here's tinc-down:

```
ip route del 10.0.0.0/24 dev $INTERFACE
ip addr del 10.0.0.3/32 dev $INTERFACE
ip link set $INTERFACE down
```

And here's the client host file:

```
Subnet = 10.0.0.3/32
```

And here's the server host file:

```
Address = foo.bar.net
Port = 655
Subnet = 10.0.0.1/32
```

....So, that's all well and good...Here's some sample output:

```
foo@local:~ » route -n
Kernel IP routing table                                                                               
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface                         
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.254   0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 enp0s3                        
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 alpha                         
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 enp0s3
```

But, I try following this guide here:  https://www.tinc-vpn.org/examples/redirect-gateway/

new tinc-up:

```
set -x
ip link set dev $INTERFACE up
#ip addr add  10.0.0.3/32 dev $INTERFACE
#ip route add 10.0.0.0/24 dev $INTERFACE
VPN_GATEWAY=10.0.0.0
ORIGINAL_GATEWAY=`ip route show | grep ^default | cut -d ' ' -f 2-5`

ip route add $REMOTEADDRESS $ORIGINAL_GATEWAY
ip route add $VPN_GATEWAY dev $INTERFACE
ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 via $VPN_GATEWAY dev $INTERFACE
ip route add 128.0.0.0/1 via $VPN_GATEWAY dev $INTERFACE
```

new tinc-down:

```
set -x
ORIGINAL_GATEWAY=`ip route show | grep ^default | cut -d ' ' -f 2-5`

ip route del $REMOTEADDRESS $ORIGINAL_GATEWAY
ip route del $VPN_GATEWAY dev $INTERFACE
ip route del 0.0.0.0/1 dev $INTERFACE
ip route del 128.0.0.0/1 dev $INTERFACE
ip link set dev $INTERFACE down
```

And the scripts now throw syntax errors for ip route and of course, nothing happens.  I've tried playing with some of the routes, I've tried explicitly defining some variables, and I've even tried running these step by step in a shell, but nothing seems to work.  The host is always unreachable.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

**EDIT 2:**
Here is the new tinc-up/down files being run with suggestions from the comments including the set-x option.  This follows a running of the tinc-up script followed by a killing of the process, which initiates the tinc-down script shown above.

```
:~ » sudo tincd -n alpha -D -d3 

tincd 1.0.31 starting, debug level 3
/dev/net/tun is a Linux tun/tap device (tun mode)
Executing script tinc-up
+ ip link set dev alpha up
+ VPN_GATEWAY=10.0.0.0
++ ip route show
++ cut -d ' ' -f 2-5
++ grep '^default'
+ ORIGINAL_GATEWAY='via 192.168.0.254 dev enp0s3'
+ ip route add via 192.168.0.254 dev enp0s3
Usage: ip route { list | flush } SELECTOR
       ip route save SELECTOR
       ip route restore
       ip route showdump
       ip route get ADDRESS [ from ADDRESS iif STRING ]
                            [ oif STRING ] [ tos TOS ]
                            [ mark NUMBER ] [ vrf NAME ]
                            [ uid NUMBER ]
       ip route { add | del | change | append | replace } ROUTE
SELECTOR := [ root PREFIX ] [ match PREFIX ] [ exact PREFIX ]
            [ table TABLE_ID ] [ vrf NAME ] [ proto RTPROTO ]
            [ type TYPE ] [ scope SCOPE ]
ROUTE := NODE_SPEC [ INFO_SPEC ]
NODE_SPEC := [ TYPE ] PREFIX [ tos TOS ]
             [ table TABLE_ID ] [ proto RTPROTO ]
             [ scope SCOPE ] [ metric METRIC ]
INFO_SPEC := NH OPTIONS FLAGS [ nexthop NH ]...
NH := [ encap ENCAPTYPE ENCAPHDR ] [ via [ FAMILY ] ADDRESS ]
        [ dev STRING ] [ weight NUMBER ] NHFLAGS
FAMILY := [ inet | inet6 | ipx | dnet | mpls | bridge | link ]
OPTIONS := FLAGS [ mtu NUMBER ] [ advmss NUMBER ] [ as [ to ] ADDRESS ]
           [ rtt TIME ] [ rttvar TIME ] [ reordering NUMBER ]
           [ window NUMBER ] [ cwnd NUMBER ] [ initcwnd NUMBER ]
           [ ssthresh NUMBER ] [ realms REALM ] [ src ADDRESS ]
           [ rto_min TIME ] [ hoplimit NUMBER ] [ initrwnd NUMBER ]
           [ features FEATURES ] [ quickack BOOL ] [ congctl NAME ]
           [ pref PREF ] [ expires TIME ]
TYPE := { unicast | local | broadcast | multicast | throw |
          unreachable | prohibit | blackhole | nat }
TABLE_ID := [ local | main | default | all | NUMBER ]
SCOPE := [ host | link | global | NUMBER ]
NHFLAGS := [ onlink | pervasive ]
RTPROTO := [ kernel | boot | static | NUMBER ]
PREF := [ low | medium | high ]
TIME := NUMBER[s|ms]
BOOL := [1|0]
FEATURES := ecn
ENCAPTYPE := [ mpls | ip | ip6 ]
ENCAPHDR := [ MPLSLABEL ]
+ ip route add 10.0.0.0 dev alpha
+ ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 via 10.0.0.0 dev alpha
+ ip route add 128.0.0.0/1 via 10.0.0.0 dev alpha
Listening on 0.0.0.0 port 655
Ready
Trying to connect to alpha (74.78.156.164 port 655)
Error while connecting to alpha (74.78.156.164 port 655): Network is unreachable
Could not set up a meta connection to alpha
Trying to re-establish outgoing connection in 5 seconds
Purging unreachable nodes
Trying to connect to alpha (74.78.156.164 port 655)
Error while connecting to alpha (74.78.156.164 port 655): Network is unreachable
Could not set up a meta connection to alpha
Trying to re-establish outgoing connection in 10 seconds
Purging unreachable nodes
Got TERM signal
Statistics for Linux tun/tap device (tun mode) /dev/net/tun:
 total bytes in:         346
 total bytes out:        306
Closing connection with charlie (MYSELF)
Executing script tinc-down
++ cut -d ' ' -f 2-5
++ grep '^default'
++ ip route show
+ ORIGINAL_GATEWAY='via 192.168.0.254 dev enp0s3'
+ ip route del via 192.168.0.254 dev enp0s3
Usage: ip route { list | flush } SELECTOR
       ip route save SELECTOR
       ip route restore
       ip route showdump
       ip route get ADDRESS [ from ADDRESS iif STRING ]
                            [ oif STRING ] [ tos TOS ]
                            [ mark NUMBER ] [ vrf NAME ]
                            [ uid NUMBER ]
       ip route { add | del | change | append | replace } ROUTE
SELECTOR := [ root PREFIX ] [ match PREFIX ] [ exact PREFIX ]
            [ table TABLE_ID ] [ vrf NAME ] [ proto RTPROTO ]
            [ type TYPE ] [ scope SCOPE ]
ROUTE := NODE_SPEC [ INFO_SPEC ]
NODE_SPEC := [ TYPE ] PREFIX [ tos TOS ]
             [ table TABLE_ID ] [ proto RTPROTO ]
             [ scope SCOPE ] [ metric METRIC ]
INFO_SPEC := NH OPTIONS FLAGS [ nexthop NH ]...
NH := [ encap ENCAPTYPE ENCAPHDR ] [ via [ FAMILY ] ADDRESS ]
        [ dev STRING ] [ weight NUMBER ] NHFLAGS
FAMILY := [ inet | inet6 | ipx | dnet | mpls | bridge | link ]
OPTIONS := FLAGS [ mtu NUMBER ] [ advmss NUMBER ] [ as [ to ] ADDRESS ]
           [ rtt TIME ] [ rttvar TIME ] [ reordering NUMBER ]
           [ window NUMBER ] [ cwnd NUMBER ] [ initcwnd NUMBER ]
           [ ssthresh NUMBER ] [ realms REALM ] [ src ADDRESS ]
           [ rto_min TIME ] [ hoplimit NUMBER ] [ initrwnd NUMBER ]
           [ features FEATURES ] [ quickack BOOL ] [ congctl NAME ]
           [ pref PREF ] [ expires TIME ]
TYPE := { unicast | local | broadcast | multicast | throw |
          unreachable | prohibit | blackhole | nat }
TABLE_ID := [ local | main | default | all | NUMBER ]
SCOPE := [ host | link | global | NUMBER ]
NHFLAGS := [ onlink | pervasive ]
RTPROTO := [ kernel | boot | static | NUMBER ]
PREF := [ low | medium | high ]
TIME := NUMBER[s|ms]
BOOL := [1|0]
FEATURES := ecn
ENCAPTYPE := [ mpls | ip | ip6 ]
ENCAPHDR := [ MPLSLABEL ]
+ ip route del dev alpha
Usage: ip route { list | flush } SELECTOR
       ip route save SELECTOR
       ip route restore
       ip route showdump
       ip route get ADDRESS [ from ADDRESS iif STRING ]
                            [ oif STRING ] [ tos TOS ]
                            [ mark NUMBER ] [ vrf NAME ]
                            [ uid NUMBER ]
       ip route { add | del | change | append | replace } ROUTE
SELECTOR := [ root PREFIX ] [ match PREFIX ] [ exact PREFIX ]
            [ table TABLE_ID ] [ vrf NAME ] [ proto RTPROTO ]
            [ type TYPE ] [ scope SCOPE ]
ROUTE := NODE_SPEC [ INFO_SPEC ]
NODE_SPEC := [ TYPE ] PREFIX [ tos TOS ]
             [ table TABLE_ID ] [ proto RTPROTO ]
             [ scope SCOPE ] [ metric METRIC ]
INFO_SPEC := NH OPTIONS FLAGS [ nexthop NH ]...
NH := [ encap ENCAPTYPE ENCAPHDR ] [ via [ FAMILY ] ADDRESS ]
        [ dev STRING ] [ weight NUMBER ] NHFLAGS
FAMILY := [ inet | inet6 | ipx | dnet | mpls | bridge | link ]
OPTIONS := FLAGS [ mtu NUMBER ] [ advmss NUMBER ] [ as [ to ] ADDRESS ]
           [ rtt TIME ] [ rttvar TIME ] [ reordering NUMBER ]
           [ window NUMBER ] [ cwnd NUMBER ] [ initcwnd NUMBER ]
           [ ssthresh NUMBER ] [ realms REALM ] [ src ADDRESS ]
           [ rto_min TIME ] [ hoplimit NUMBER ] [ initrwnd NUMBER ]
           [ features FEATURES ] [ quickack BOOL ] [ congctl NAME ]
           [ pref PREF ] [ expires TIME ]
TYPE := { unicast | local | broadcast | multicast | throw |
          unreachable | prohibit | blackhole | nat }
TABLE_ID := [ local | main | default | all | NUMBER ]
SCOPE := [ host | link | global | NUMBER ]
NHFLAGS := [ onlink | pervasive ]
RTPROTO := [ kernel | boot | static | NUMBER ]
PREF := [ low | medium | high ]
TIME := NUMBER[s|ms]
BOOL := [1|0]
FEATURES := ecn
ENCAPTYPE := [ mpls | ip | ip6 ]
ENCAPHDR := [ MPLSLABEL ]
+ ip route del 0.0.0.0/1 dev alpha
+ ip route del 128.0.0.0/1 dev alpha
+ ip link set dev alpha down
Terminating
```

**EDIT 3:**

I find that changing to:

```
ORIGINAL_GATEWAY=`ip route show | grep ^default | cut -d ' ' -f 3-5`
```

gives 
192.168.0.254 dev enp0s3

and now my scripts don't throw syntax errors for iproute...However, they do complain about the following:

```
+ ip route add 192.168.0.254 dev enp0s3
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
```

Comment: Where exactly are the syntax errors? If this is a bash shell script, run it with bash -x tinc-up to see where it fails.

Comment: Updated question with output.

Comment: It's `ip link set dev $INTERFACE up`. With the `dev` keyword. Same thing for down.

Comment: Add `set -x` to your script to see the commands that are run.

Comment: Added the changes...It seems that the issue is in the *del* command and the *add via* syntax.